# Mqtt client UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: node.js, ssl, mqtt, mosca

I'm running a `mosca` broker on my backend and i'm using the standard `mqtt` npm lib. I have encountered an issue, which i can't seem to grasp on whats going on when setting SSL.
Have generated self-signed ca, server and client certs and have setup mosca like so

```
var mosca = require('mosca');
var path = require('path');
var setup = {
  port: 8883,
  secure: {
    keyPath: path.join(__dirname, 'server.key'),
    certPath: path.join(__dirname, 'server.crt'),
    caPaths: path.join(__dirname, 'ca.crt'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
}

var server = new mosca.Server(setup);

server.on('ready', function () {
  console.log('rdy');
});
```

Mosca broker reports no issues, and runs smoothly with these certificates. However when using the `mqtt` client lib to connect to this broker I get the following

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var fs = require('fs');
var tls = require('tls');

var client = mqtt.connect('ssl://localhost:8883', tls.connect({
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'client.key')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ca.crt')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'client.crt')),
  passphrase: 'client'
}));
client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

When trying to connect, the error event is triggered, with the following error:

```
[Error: unable to verify the first certificate] code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
```

I have tried setting `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"` but to no effect.

Client certificates have been tested with different clients, and it works fine with no issues. What am i doing wrong here?

nodejs version: 0.12.7
npm mosca version: 0.32.1,
npm mqtt version: 1.4.3

Comment: Solved the issue by implementing two interfaces, one for localhost connections (no ssl), one for incoming connections (with ssl).
https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/395

Comment: hey im having unable to connect to mqtt server using tls. I'm always getting an EADDRNOTAVAIL error. Is this code working? There aren't many examples on this!